# Android cardview zoom-in and zoom-out animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-cardview

I am developing a simple image quiz application where i need a zoom-in and zoom-out animation for the card view used in the layout. I need to zoom-in the selected card by say 10% and zoom-out and blur the remaining cards by 10%. I have attached the layout for reference and need some inputs on how it can be achieved. The entire layout presented here is inside a custom ViewPager.

[cardview-animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5ita.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this....

```
View gridView;                    // Assume your items are attached to this View
ArrayList<View> itemViewList;     // Each item views

public void selectItem(int index) {
    for(int i=0; i<itemViewList.size; i++) {
        if(index == i)
            itemViewList.get(i).animate().scaleX(1.05f).scaleY(1.05f).setDuration(150);
        else
            itemViewList.get(i).animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(150);
    }
}
```

Btw you cannot achieve FANCY blur effect by this way.
[Check this article.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826057/android-imageview-blur-animation)